# How to put a pre-loader backgroud for images on ioinc 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, lazy-loading, ionic4

## My question is **how to put a background color ( preloader ) until the images get load?!**

I'm building an **e-commerce mobile app with** `ionic 4.1` the problem is their too many images on the page so when it gets loaded the app looks **ugly**!

I use `ion-img` tag for **lazy loading** witch even make things worse the images before it's loaded shows a **broken mark** -_- then get loaded as normal!

I have searched for this and I found a lib called `ionic-image-loader` so I give it a try and it doesn't work with ionic 4 unfortunately!

**What I need is something like this! if you open this article I need the same effect that happened on images when it gets loading!**

> https://onezero.medium.com/google-just-showed-us-the-future-of-gaming-37ccec59e2dd

Answer (score 0):

[**EDIT**]

So I've made some researches and came with this result:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  
  var placeholder = document.querySelector('.placeholder'),
      small = placeholder.querySelector('.img-small')
  
  // 1: load small image and show it
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = small.src;
  img.onload = function () {
    small.classList.add('loaded');
  };
  
  // 2: load large image
  var imgLarge = new Image();
  imgLarge.src = placeholder.dataset.large; 
  imgLarge.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function(){ imgLarge.classList.add('loaded'); }, 2000);
  };
  placeholder.appendChild(imgLarge);
}
```

```css
.placeholder {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.placeholder img {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

.placeholder img.loaded {
  opacity: 1;
}

.img-small {
  filter: blur(50px);
  /* this is needed so Safari keeps sharp edges */
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="placeholder" data-large="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1800/1*sg-uLNm73whmdOgKlrQdZA.jpeg">
            <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/freeze/max/27/1*sg-uLNm73whmdOgKlrQdZA.jpeg?q=20" class="img-small">
            <div style="padding-bottom: 66.6%;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Source: https://jmperezperez.com/medium-image-progressive-loading-placeholder/

**How does it work?**

It is simple, you need 2 images (a really small one and your regular one).

This is the really small image (easy to load)

[image: The small one]

This is the regular image (longer to load)

[image: Your regular one]

And the javascript launches a transition between these 2 images when the larger one is loaded. There you go!

Comment: Ionic now has a feature like this built-in called ( ion-skeleton-text ) with same animation and everything and I use it actually **my problem is just images need to give it a background when it loaded using ion-img something like medium.com**

Comment: if you open this article you will understand what I mean **take a look at how images get loaded?!**

https://onezero.medium.com/google-just-showed-us-the-future-of-gaming-37ccec59e2dd